# Java RMI and multiple networks

Tags: java, networking, rmi

I am with some doubts about Java RMI, as its written in the title.
My problem is:
Suppose I have three different Networks: A, B and C.
In the network A I have a RMI service running, and I want to access that service using networks B and C.
Is that possible? or Do I have to use a Web-Service for the job?

Thks.

Comment: I think you need to read this FAQ about RMI as posted on oracle website http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html

Comment: @VishalK it would be better to post the link to the Q/A instead of letting OP (and every visitor) to get it by ourselves.

Comment: @VishalK why could not you simply answer to my quest instead of sharing a link?

Comment: @tsukanomon He posted it as a comment, not an answer. He is quite correct: you should read item A.1 of that FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fundamental assumption in RMI(/JRMP) that every server host has a 'most public' IP address that is visible to everybody, which can be set in RMI via the system property 'java.rmi.server.hostname'. This IP address is set in the remote stub.

If your network topology doesn't conform to this description, you are out of luck.